# Как писать "не()гоже"?

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно

Как пишется "не()гоже" - слитно или раздельно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нормативные словари фиксируют слитное написание этого наречия: *негоже.*

Answer (score 0):

Негоже пишется слитно=нехорошо.